# How to properly size a logo in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="./styles.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img style="padding: 0%;"src="./imgs/HHLogo-1 (1).png" alt="" width="30" height="auto" class="d-inline-block align-top">
        </a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to stick a company logo in the navbar in bootstrap5.  The image is an png. For some reason the image is properly sized but the navbar is way too thick.  How can I size the navbar appropriately? [image: This is the logo].  I have tried everything I have came across on here on stackoverflow and other forums/websites.  I have tried changed padding and max navbar height among other things.  Can you help me out?? Thank you so much any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/6wNrpHc

Comment: Yes except make the navbar shorter and the image shorter as well.  Could you help me?

Comment: Should the navbar be the default size?

Comment: About half the size of the image.  Or default size.  How are you changing the size??

Comment: for `img` im set `width: 100%`. But the point is that the logo itself is very large by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added two selectors to your css - `.navbar-brand { ... }` and `.navbar-brand > img { ... }`:

```
.navbar-brand {
  width: 150px;
}

.navbar-brand > img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Now you can adjust the size of the `navbar` and `logo` yourself by changing the width of the `.navbar-brand { ... }` selector.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  width: 150px;
}

.navbar-brand > img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="./styles.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img style="padding: 0%;"src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHYjg.png" alt="" width="30" height="auto" class="d-inline-block align-top">
        </a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @MattSalem, If my answer helped you, then mark it as solved by checking the checkbox to the left of my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
nav a.navbar-brand {
        max-width: 150px;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Still doesnt work. Any other ideas? Im all out.  It might be a bootstrap thing instead of a css issue

Comment: could you please use snippet ? or add your url

Comment: i did a mistaake with my css class

Comment: What was the mistake?

Comment: Make your logo a .svg instead of .png (;

Comment: the name of my class